# Is it a causative morpheme or a modal morpheme?

Tags: english, modal-verbs, valency, causative

Let us take the verb 'get', we can say both:

1- Someone gets to take something

2- Someone gets someone to take something

In the 1st sentence, 'get' is a modal morpheme, but in the other sentence 'get' is a causative morpheme. This case is not only found in English, in Riffian there is also this confusion:

1- i-ga ad i-ksi ci (he-did FUT he-take something)

2- i-ga x-k ad t-ksi-d ci (he-did on-you FUT you-take something)

How is it possible that a morpheme can be either causative or modal ? Can we speak of "ambi-auxiliarity" ?

Comment: "Someone get to take something" isn't grammatical and "Someone get someone to take something" is only grammatical in the imperative mood, in which case "get" is no longer a modal.

Comment: Why shouldn't it? _Get_ is also used in English to form passives. So what?

Comment: @ubadub if I believe ngraw viewer, 'get to take' is a predicate heavily used in english: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=get+to+take&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cget%20to%20take%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @colin what is it the role of a linguist or of a researcher? Indeed, get (+ past participle ) can be a passive morpheme, but why does that exist only in the past?

Comment: @amegnunsen: the passive 'get' certainly does not exist only in the past: "They're gonna get caught!" In answer to your question: of course a linguist can ask any question they like, but not all questions have interesting answers.

Comment: @colin can we continue to discuss respectfully? As far as I know 'caught' is the past participle of 'catch'. Is it possible in English to say 'get catching'? If 'get' works like the auxiliary 'be', why is the present participle forbidden?

Comment: @amegnunsen: I hope we are. The _get_ passive is precisely that: "the _get_ passive". NObody is saying that _get_ can replace _be_ in all contexts.

Comment: @amegnunsen OP didn't say "get to take," they said "*someone* get to take." This is ungrammatical. See: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=someone+get+to+take&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=

Comment: Can you provide proper grammatical examples of your two 'gets'? And also a free translation of your Riffian examples so we can see what's going on.

Comment: @gaston Riffian is just here to emphasize this study case. There is the same thing in English. Translation of Riffian examples: 1- He gets to take something; 2- He gets you to take something

Comment: @ubadub Change 'someone' by 'you' for example.

Comment: Words can be ambiguous and even one word can have distinct valence frames with various roles such as causee (in your second example).

Comment: @atamiri A verb can have a lot of semantic features (Tense, Aspect, Modal, Voice) without adding any other morphemes. The syntactic or situational context allows to decode the message. Moreover, one verbal morpheme can have several options inside of each of these features (T1/T2, A1/A2/A3, M1, V1/V2). In an imaginary language, T1 could be the present, T2 the past, A3 the progressive and so on. But that concerns the verbs, what is it the case for the auxiliaries? Have you ever seen an abbreviation as TAM for the auxiliaries? It seems that the auxiliaries are always described as mono-referential

Comment: @amegnunsen you can say "get catching," e.g. a baseball coach telling a player "you better get catching..."

Comment: These are two different idioms involving _get_. (There are a lot more.) _`X` get to `VP`_ means `X` is allowed to `VP`, so you can think of it as having a deontic modal sense (no epistemic sense, though, so it's not a full modal). On the other hand, _`X` get `Y` to `VP`_ means that `X` causes `Y` to `VP`, so you can think of it as being causative. _Get_ is, after all, the causative/inchoative form of both _be_  -- _He got married_ -- **and** _have_ -- _He got a cold_. Idioms have special affordances and grammar; it doesn't have to much to with _get_ as with idioms.

Comment: @ubadub 'catching' here is a gerund. Gerund is different from present participle.

Comment: @amegnunsen I'm fairly sure that's the participle, being used as an adjective. Get can go with adjectives, "get dark," for example, and the present participle can be used as an adjective.

Comment: You confuse syntax with semantics, TAM features aren’t semantic.

Comment: TAM features are abstract labels and not data, so they're anything you want to call them. Semantic, syntactic, morphological, pragmatic,however your particular theory insists on handling them. Theory is not data.

Answer (score 1):

Words can mean different things.

(I know this answer is terse but I'm not sure what else you expect. There's no rule that says "Languages can't have homophonous morphemes.")

Comment: @ubadud I agree, but it seems that these two 'get''s belong to the same paradigm or in any case they cannot be combined syntactically. If they were analytical verbs, that should be possible.